# Geojson features click infowindow display triggers drag event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

I have an issue with google maps and the data layer.
When i load a geojson file containing Points and binding a click event to these markers to open an infoWindow, the maps starts dragging as you can see in this snippet.

```js
var infoWindow;
    function init(){
    // ... init map
        var lat = 45.553349634491; var lng =-73.611958006357;
      var zoom =18;

        var mapOptions = { zoom : zoom, disableDefaultUI:true, zoomControl:true, };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
         map.setCenter({lat:lat,lng:lng});
         // load geojson
         map.data.loadGeoJson("http://adam.cherti.name/CREE TA VILLE/get/poteaux.php?lat_nwest=45.55350176872861&lng_nwest=-73.61094413134936&lat_seast=45.55319749984158&lng_seast=-73.6129879746187&date=2015/5/21_21:12:01");
    
         map.data.addListener("mousedown", function(e)
         {
    
            var pos = e.latLng;
            if(!infoWindow )
                infoWindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            var html ='hey !';
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map);
        });

    }
    $(document).ready(function(){init()});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyAcPswPf-CHjpRLEqDYPj7hBeycynREWpY&sensor=true"></script>

<body style="width:100%; height:100%">
  <div style="width:100%; height:500px" id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried randomly a function stopPropagation(event) when the click event is triggered because i thought it would "stop" the event from triggering to the map but it didn't worked. Here is the code of the func :

```
function stopPropagation(myEvent){ 
    if(!myEvent){ 
        myEvent=window.event; 
    } 
    myEvent.cancelBubble=true; 
    if(myEvent.stopPropagation){ 
       myEvent.stopPropagation(); 
}
```

If anyonye have found the solution for this issue, please let me know !

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using a `click` event, you are using a `mousedown` event.  Using a `click` event fixes the issue for me.

```js
var infoWindow;
    function init(){
    // ... init map
        var lat = 45.553349634491; var lng =-73.611958006357;
      var zoom =18;

        var mapOptions = { zoom : zoom, disableDefaultUI:true, zoomControl:true, };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
         map.setCenter({lat:lat,lng:lng});
         // load geojson
         map.data.loadGeoJson("http://adam.cherti.name/CREE TA VILLE/get/poteaux.php?lat_nwest=45.55350176872861&lng_nwest=-73.61094413134936&lat_seast=45.55319749984158&lng_seast=-73.6129879746187&date=2015/5/21_21:12:01");
    
         map.data.addListener("click", function(e)
         {
    
            var pos = e.latLng;
            if(!infoWindow )
                infoWindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            var html ='hey !';
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map);
        });

    }
    $(document).ready(function(){init()});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<body style="width:100%; height:100%">
  <div style="width:100%; height:500px" id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```